# FreeRadius Live AP login User-Password blank?

Tags: freeradius

I'm kinda new to FreeRadius. I managed to setup a server with rlm_rest enabled. my (first) goal is to login via a username and password, that is verified with an external api.

when i use radtest with a username and password, i get the following output on the server and receive an Access-Accept

```
Sent Access-Request Id 155 from 0.0.0.0:46565 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 90
    User-Name = "username"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
    NAS-Port = 10
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "password"
```

however when i try to login on a live AP (WAP300N Linksys) with radius setup, the User-Password is not passed, see log output server below:

```
Received Access-Request Id 184 from 192.168.1.8:49250 to 192.168.1.29:1812 length 181
   User-Name = "admin"
   NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.10
   NAS-Identifier = "RalinkAP0"
   NAS-Port = 0
   Called-Station-Id = "C0-56-27-8D-E4-61"
   Calling-Station-Id = "44-00-10-D3-9B-BC"
   Framed-MTU = 1400
   NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
   EAP-Message = 0x020a002b190017030100200f8d3de6cc2558d4ea01c8f5a5b4a7feb747c427121cfa5a837d1cdd4d552dbd
   State = 0x3e453e88364f273bd4879022bb95e46c
   Message-Authenticator = 0xecb9642bb2342557885edba46f52e0cc
```

does this have anything to do with the server configuration? Or is the AP clearing the password for some reason. I'm trying to login on an Iphone...maybe that is the issue?

thanks in advance

Stefan

Comment: Any solution found? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @chrischubb idk if you figured it out in the end... but i think it was a misconfiguration of the server. In the end some one else made it work. if you want i can give you his details.

Comment: Thanks @stefan-guy, I learned that the default request comes in the EAP message as a hash of pre-defined values, not the cleartext password like the testing command line application. All default protocols currently hash data and expect the Radius server to hash the same data on the back end and compare hashes.